# Обмен сигналами между родителем и потомком

Tags: c++, linux, c

У меня следующая идея программы: родитель создает потомка при помощи fork(), потомок выполняет какие-либо действия, а родитель периодически посылает ему запросы о состоянии при помощи linux сигналов (SIGUSR1). Потомок при помощи тех же сигналов отвечает: посылает SIGUSR1 в случае, если все в порядке и SIGUSR2 если есть проблемы. Проблема в том, что у меня не получается перехватить сигналы в родителе. Скажите, где я ошибся или что я не учел.
Заранее спасибо.

Собственно, текст программы:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

volatile sig_atomic_t reply_status = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t status_flag = 0;

void ParentHandler(int signum, siginfo_t* info, void*)
{
    if (signum == SIGUSR1)
    {
        std::cout << "Parent got signal: " << "Child ok" << std::endl;
        reply_status = 0;
    }

    if (signum == SIGUSR2)
    {
        std::cout << "Parent got signal: " << "Child bad" << std::endl;
        reply_status = -1;
    }

    if (signum == SIGCHLD)
    {
        std::cout << "Parent got signal: " << "Child closed" << std::endl;
        switch (info->si_code)
        {
        case CLD_EXITED :
            std::cout << "Child exited" << std::endl;
            reply_status = 1;
            break;
        case CLD_KILLED :
        case CLD_DUMPED :
            std::cout << "Child killed" << std::endl;
            reply_status = -2;
            break;
        default :
            std::cout << "Something with child" << std::endl;
            reply_status = 0;
        }
    }
}

void ChildHandler(int signum, siginfo_t* info, void*)
{
    std::cout << "Child got signal" << signum << std::endl;

    if (status_flag == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Child replied ok" << std::endl;
        kill(info->si_pid, SIGUSR1); //после посыла сигнала родитель крашится
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "replied bad" << std::endl;
        kill(info->si_pid, SIGUSR2);
    }
}


int ParentBody(pid_t child)
{
    std::cout << "Parent started" << std::endl;

    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(action));
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    action.sa_sigaction = ParentHandler;

    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, nullptr);
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &action, nullptr);
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &action, nullptr);

    while (!reply_status)
    {
        sleep(1);

        std::cout << "Sending request to child" << std::endl;
        kill(child, SIGUSR1);

        timespec t;
        t.tv_sec = 0;
        t.tv_nsec = 10000000;
        nanosleep(&t, nullptr);
    }

    return 0;
}

int ChildBody()
{
    std::cout << "Child started" << std::endl;

    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(action));
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    action.sa_sigaction = ChildHandler;

    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, nullptr);

    sleep(10);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Starting!" << std::endl;

    pid_t child = fork();

    switch (child)
    {
    case -1:
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        break;

    case 0:
        return ChildBody();

    default:
        return ParentBody(child);
    }
}
```

Выполнение программы останавливается после того как родитель получает ответный сигнал SIGUSR1 от потомка

Comment: Так у вас дочерний процесс сразу выходит, родитель получает `SIGCHLD` и тоже выходит.

Comment: `ParentHandler` вызывается, `reply_status` выставляется в 1, цикл `while (!reply_status)` в `ParentBody` прерывается, родитель выходит.

Comment: Похоже, что вы все же не правы. до SIGCHLD дело не доходит. Программа останавливается на SIGUSR1, обработка SIGCHLD не проходит

Comment: Как вы это определили? У меня такое ощущение, что вы занимаетесь printf-oтладкой. Так или иначе, всю обработку сигналов следует выкинуть и переключится на другие механизмы IPC.

Comment: Очень просто - стрелочка дебаггера показывает на строчку "nanosleep(&t, nullptr);", которая внутри цикла while в момент прихода SIGUSR1

Comment: @Oleg, отладка `fork()`'ающегося процесса в отладчике — дело нетривиальное, если хочешь, чтобы тебе поверили что ты не наделал в оном ошибок, то лог отладки в студию... иначе покажи **вывод** самого приложения и укажи, что в нём не так... как @VTT  уже упоминал, печатать в обработчике сигналов — дело, вообще говоря, опасное, но в данном случае это не должно вызывать проблем...

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых для общения между процессами следует использовать другие механизмы, а не сигналы. Во-вторых в обработчике сигнала можно безопасно вызвать только [async-signal-safe функции](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, однако во-первых я общаюсь не между потоками, а между процессами. во-вторых, я убрал все выводы в консоль из обоих обработчиков и легче не стало. Программа все равно крашится по приходу необработанного сигнала SIGUSR1

Comment: @Oleg Ответ я подправил, а в каком месте крашится?

Comment: Потомок принимает сигнал нормально и его обрабатывает, отправляет сигнал обратно родителю. Насколько я понимаю, крашится родитель, он не перехватывает ответный сигнал потомка

Comment: @Oleg Так не перехватывает или крашится? А если крашится, то в каком месте (какой стек вызовов)?

Comment: Согласен, не верно выразился. Программа останавливается, так как получает сигнал SIGUSR1

Comment: @Oleg, добавь хотя бы вывод в вопрос... а то угадайка какая-то...

Comment: Добавил комментарий

Comment: А какая принципиальная разница в данном случае между потоком и процессом? Вы хотите получить IPC, ну так и получайте.

Comment: @0andriy Принципиальная разница в том, что у каждого процесса свое адресное пространство.